# How to permanently change the default preselected application type from Plain C Applicatoin to Plain C++ Application in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

In Qt Creator I am programming in C++ exclusively and when I create new projects via ctrl + N or File > New File or Project, in the Non-Qt project section the Plain C Application is preselected.

Well, I can't tell you how many times did I forget to switch Plain C Application to Plain C++ Application. It would be so great if I could somehow make PLain C++ Application the preselected choice instead of Plain C Application as it is now.

How to do that? Is it possible to achieve this via some option in settings or via some simple edit in some Qt Creator config file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting but on mac OS I found at least two way to do it, I'm not familiar with Qt Creator so maybe another better way exist.

Go to `/Users/YourUsername/PathToTheQtApp/Contents/Resources/templates/wizards/projects/`

In my computer this is : `/Users/bso/Qt/Qt\ Creator.app/Contents/Resources/templates/wizards/projects/`

1. **The drastic way :** remove the folder named 'plainc'
2. **The Proper way :** in the folder 'plainc' open wizard.json and replace `"id": "A.Plain C Application"` with `"id": "S.Plain C Application"` (replace **A** with **S**). This work because ids are sorted and the id of the cpp project template is `"R.Plain Cpp Application"`. So we simply re-ordered them.

On Windows they are maybe also a wizard.json somewhere on the installation folder for the plainc project template, if your find one do the same trick, change the id.

Comment: PS : if you do this modification while Qt Creator is running you will need to restart the app to see the effect.